# Html table not display properly while too many or table text is too long in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html, flutter-html

I'm trying to display an HTML table in my app but arise an overflow issue.
I'm using **flutter_html** dependence.

This is my HTML table code

```html
<p>Destruction of the<strong> ciliary ganglion</strong> interrupts <strong>postganglionic parasympathetic fibers</strong>, which innervate the sphincter pupillae and ciliaris; this results in-</p><ul><li><strong>loss of the direct pupillary reflex, </strong></li><li><strong>mydriasis, and </strong></li><li><strong>loss of accommodation.</strong></li></ul><p><strong>TREASURE</strong></p><table><tbody><tr><td><p><strong>Ganglion </strong></p></td><td><p><strong>Topographically Related To </strong></p></td><td><p><strong>Functionally Related To </strong></p></td><td><p><strong>Supplies </strong></p></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>Otic</strong></p></td><td><p>Mandibular nerve&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>Glossopharyngeal nerve&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>Parotid gland</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>Pterygopalatine</strong></p></td><td><p>Maxillary nerve&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>Greater petrosal nerve&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>Lacrimal, nasal, palatine, pharyngeal glands</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>Submandibular</strong></p></td><td><p>Lingual nerve</p></td><td><p>Chorda tympani nerve</p></td><td><p>Submandibular and sublingual glands</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>Ciliary</strong></p></td><td><p>Nasociliary nerve</p></td><td><p>Oculomotor nerve</p></td><td><p>Ciliaris</p><p>Sphincter and dilator pupillae</p></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This is my flutter code

```
Html(
    data: htmlText,
    style: {
        "table": Style(),
        // some other granular customizations are also possible
        "tr": Style(
        border:
          Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
        ),
        "th": Style(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        "td": Style(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        ),
    }
)
```

[image: Output image]

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

try Add more this field to make table scrollable

```
customRender: {
    "table": (context, child) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: (context.tree as TableLayoutElement)
                            .toWidget(context),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>Destruction of the<strong> ciliary ganglion</strong> interrupts <strong>postganglionic parasympathetic fibers</strong>, which innervate the sphincter pupillae and ciliaris; this results in-</p><ul><li><strong>loss of the direct pupillary reflex, </strong></li><li><strong>mydriasis, and </strong></li><li><strong>loss of accommodation.</strong></li></ul><p><strong>TREASURE</strong></p><table><colgroup><col width="25%" /><col width="25%" /><col width="25%" /><col width="25%" /></colgroup><tbody><tr><td><p><strong>Ganglion </strong></p></td><td><p><strong>Topographically Related To </strong></p></td><td><p><strong>Functionally Related To </strong></p></td><td><p><strong>Supplies </strong></p></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>Otic</strong></p></td><td><p>Mandibular nerve&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>Glossopharyngeal nerve&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>Parotid gland</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>Pterygopalatine</strong></p></td><td><p>Maxillary nerve&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>Greater petrosal nerve&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>Lacrimal, nasal, palatine, pharyngeal glands</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>Submandibular</strong></p></td><td><p>Lingual nerve</p></td><td><p>Chorda tympani nerve</p></td><td><p>Submandibular and sublingual glands</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>Ciliary</strong></p></td><td><p>Nasociliary nerve</p></td><td><p>Oculomotor nerve</p></td><td><p>Ciliaris</p><p>Sphincter and dilator pupillae</p></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Add  tag in  tag. Inside  add  tag.  have width attribute. so give all  tag give equal width.

For example
I have four column so I give all  tag width=25%